# gdal translate scale and save to jpg using python

Tags: python, image, gis, gdal

I know how to use gdal translate to scale and save to jpg via cmd line:

```
gdal_translate image.bsq image.jpg -of JPEG -outsize 10% 10% -scale
```

This produces (what I call a nice image):

[image]

I would like to produce similar image via python, something like:

```
from osgeo import gdal
img_bsq  = 'image.bsq'
img_jpg  = 'image.jpg'  
gdal.Translate(img_jpg, img_bsq, format='JPEG', width=1024, height=0, scaleParams=[[500,1000,10,20]])
```

The issue I think is how to properly select `scaleParams`. It seems the `-scale` on the cmd line compute values automatically, as per `man gdal_translate`:

```
-scale [src_min src_max [dst_min dst_max]]:
           Rescale the input pixels values from the range src_min to src_max to the range dst_min to dst_max. If omitted the output range is 0
           to 255. If omitted the input range is automatically computed from the source data.
```

Any tip on how to select `scaleParams` (or other relevant options)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should be able to leave it blank here as well, like:

```
gdal.Translate(img_jpg, img_bsq, format='JPEG', width=1024, height=0, scaleParams=[[]])
```

This causes GDAL to make a guess itself, as described in the docs:

> -scale [src_min src_max [dst_min dst_max]]:
>       Rescale the input pixels values from the range src_min to src_max to the range dst_min to dst_max. If omitted the output range is 0 to
>   255. If omitted the input range is automatically computed from the source data.

http://www.gdal.org/gdal_translate.html

Alternatively, you could also retrieve the statistics (per band) and make something up yourself.

Getting the statistics:

```
ds = gdal.Open('img_bsq')
stats = [ds.GetRasterBand(i+1).GetStatistics(True, True) for i in range(ds.RasterCount)]
ds = None

vmin, vmax, vmean, vstd = zip(*stats)
```

With those statistics you should be able to come up with some desired stretching. If you want to scale between the min and max for each band you could do:

```
scaleParams = list(zip(*[vmin, vmax]))
```

Or if you want to use the absolute highest and lowest (over all bands)

```
scaleParams = [[min(vmin), max(vmax)]]
```

etc.

Comment: A minor thing, have to use `scaleParams=[[]]` for the automatic approach.

Comment: @KcFnMi You're right, I'll edit the post. It just clips to byte if you use single brackets.